# Getting fetch_object() error on a successful query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in C:\.....php on line 136
```

Here's the code:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO partlistlist ( P_fam , P_code , P_name, P_var , P_ver , P_lnk , P_fol , P_Notes , P_status , P_op ) VALUES ( \"".$mod_fam ."\", \"".$mod_code ."\", \"".$mod_name ."\", \"".$mod_var  ."\", 1 , \"".$mod_lnk  ."\", \"".$mod_fold ."\", \"".$mod_note     ."\", \"".$mod_stat ."\", \"".  $_SESSION['wh_pwd_usr']."\"  ) "));
{
    echo "<br>Articolo creato con successo";
    $created_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
    if (!$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM partlistlist WHERE P_id = $created_id LIMIT 1"))
        echo "Error";
    $row = $result->fetch_object();
    $P_id = $created_id;

    if (!$result_clonepart = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM partlist WHERE K_pid = $old_P_id"))
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
    else
    {
        if ($result_clonepart->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($row_clonepart = $result_clonepart->fetch_object())
            {
                if (!$result_clonepart = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO partlist ( K_ref ,K_pid ,K_iid ,K_qty ,K_subpid, K_stat ) VALUES ( \"".$row_clonepart->K_ref      ."\" ,\"". $P_id    ."\" ,\"".$row_clonepart->K_iid     ."\" ,\"".$row_clonepart->K_qty     ."\" ,\"".$row_clonepart->K_subpid   ."\" ,\"".$row_clonepart->K_stat       ."\")"))
                    echo "Error";
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Line 136 is:

```
while ($row_clonepart = $result_clonepart->fetch_object())
```

How can $result_clonepart not be an object, if the the num_rows check is good?

Comment: What do you get if you print `$result_clonepart` after executing? `die(var_dump($result_clonepart));`

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(8) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Actually that will never be on the internet, it's just a local management website - btw they're escaped and checked quite carefully (according to what I know (that's not much))

Comment: @SimoneApprendista As long as your are using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, `trim` and validate them against a regex you should be good protected against sql queries without using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop you are reassigning `$result_clonepart` (what you probably don't want to do). If that query fails your script will stop with a fatal error.

Use a different variable name (if you don't want to use the same variable name) or break the loop on failure (if you are reassigning intentionally)

```
while ($row_clonepart = $result_clonepart->fetch_object()) {
  //     VVVVVVVVVVV     Here is the reassignment
  if (!$result_clonepart = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO partlist ( K_ref ,K_pid ,K_iid ,K_qty ,K_subpid, K_stat ) VALUES ( \"".$row_clonepart->K_ref      ."\" ,\"". $P_id    ."\" ,\"".$row_clonepart->K_iid     ."\" ,\"".$row_clonepart->K_qty     ."\" ,\"".$row_clonepart->K_subpid   ."\" ,\"".$row_clonepart->K_stat       ."\")"))
      echo "Error";
      //You could insert a break statement if you are reassigning the variable intentionally
}
```